# How to apply "Uniform" stretch property to a composite path with gradients in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

Folks

I am trying to draw my company's logo vectorially with XAML, in order to put it inside UI containers whenever it is convenient.

The only requisite is that the logo won't be clipped or deformed, so the "Uniform" stretch property is what I am looking for.

Sample "semi-working" code is below:

```
<Grid Width="160" Height="153" >
    <Rectangle Clip="M 80,0 c 41.793,0 75.879,34.086 75.879,75.878 0,0.75 -0.015,1.496 -0.036,2.24 l -33.846,-57.969 -42.204,80.387 -39.421,-68.175 -35.758,34.917 c 4.294,-37.769 36.501,-67.278 75.386,-67.278 z" Margin="0">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="44,14" Center="44,44" RadiusX="125" RadiusY="125" MappingMode="Absolute">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1C545C" Offset="0.63"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3BB3C3" Offset="0.23"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>              
         </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Clip="M 151,102 c -10.528,29.287 -38.601,50.33 -71.436,50.33 -36.935,0 -67.845,-26.625 -74.533,-61.662 l 32.586,-31.299 42.204,75.131 44.986,-84.096 26.193,51.596 z">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="100" RadiusX="100" GradientOrigin="49,87" Center="49,87" MappingMode="Absolute">
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MarinhoMiotec}" Offset="0.27"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF003052" Offset="0.63"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

The problem is: when I put this grid inside another icon-sized grid, the drawing does not shrink to uniformly fit inside it.

I guess it is so because the grid where the rectangles are drawn has fixed heigth and width. I already tried to create a single discontinuous path, but then I could not put different colors on each half of the logo.

Should I chose a different container, or should I make the coordinates relative, or use a transform, or create a style, or make a brush... I am confused with so many possible lines of action...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your logo inside a **ViewBox**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx

Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="160" Height="153" >
            <Rectangle Clip="M 80,0 c 41.793,0 75.879,34.086 75.879,75.878 0,0.75 -0.015,1.496 -0.036,2.24 l -33.846,-57.969 -42.204,80.387 -39.421,-68.175 -35.758,34.917 c 4.294,-37.769 36.501,-67.278 75.386,-67.278 z" Margin="0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="44,14" Center="44,44" RadiusX="125" RadiusY="125" MappingMode="Absolute">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1C545C" Offset="0.63"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3BB3C3" Offset="0.23"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Clip="M 151,102 c -10.528,29.287 -38.601,50.33 -71.436,50.33 -36.935,0 -67.845,-26.625 -74.533,-61.662 l 32.586,-31.299 42.204,75.131 44.986,-84.096 26.193,51.596 z">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="100" RadiusX="100" GradientOrigin="49,87" Center="49,87" MappingMode="Absolute">
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MarinhoMiotec}" Offset="0.27"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF003052" Offset="0.63"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

This will render the logo in a 50x50 grid cell.

Comment: Already tried the ViewBox, but since my root container is a grid with fixed dimensions (need to be this way, I think), the content does not resize...

Comment: Let me know if the added code sample is not what your repro is.

Comment: I don't know what I have done before, but your code really works. Now I can get the result I was looking for. Thank you very much!